# Mapping set of keys to a matching list of lists

Tags: kotlin

What is an idiomatic way to map keys to a matching list of lists? An example - given:

```
val s = listOf(1, 9)
val u = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(1, 4, 7), listOf(1, 5, 9))
```

I would like to have a `Map<Int, List<List<Int>>>` such that every key in `s` is mapped to a list of lists containing that key:

```
{1=[ [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9] ], 9=[ [1, 5, 9] ]}
```

The following:

```
s.groupBy({ it }, { x -> u.filter { it.contains(x) } })
```

produces:

```
{1=[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]]], 9=[[[1, 5, 9]]]}
```

which is not quite right and it isn't clear how to flatten the result to the expected shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatic to me would be `s.groupBy(....)` The answer by @Omar Mainegra  - `s.groupBy(...).mapValues( flatten )` absolutely works but it looks like a hack where the initial result needs some extra massaging.

The issue is with the implementation of `groupBy` and more specifically with `groupByTo`:

```
public inline fun <T, K, V, M : MutableMap<in K, MutableList<V>>> Iterable<T>.groupByTo(destination: M, keySelector: (T) -> K, valueTransform: (T) -> V): M {
    for (element in this) {
        val key = keySelector(element)
        val list = destination.getOrPut(key) { ArrayList<V>() }
        list.add(valueTransform(element))
    }
    return destination
}
```

The implementation wraps the values associated with a key in a list because in general multiple values can be associated with a key which is not the case here
where values in `s` are unique which means that `groupBy` is the wrong function to use. The right function is [`associateWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-with.html):

```
s.associateWith { x -> u.filter { it.contains(x) } }
```

produces:

```
{1=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]], 9=[[1, 5, 9]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [`associateWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-with.html) and use it like this:

```
s.associateWith { num -> u.filter { list -> num in list } }
```

Output:

> {1=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]], 9=[[1, 5, 9]]}

<sub>I recommended [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) at first, but you can shorten the code even further if you use `associateWith`. Thanks to [Abhay Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4129661/abhay-agarwal) who recommended it.</sub>

Comment: Your solution is nice but, I've further improved it.  
`s.associateWith { num -> u.filter { it.contains(num) } }`

Comment: @Abhay Agarwal good idea! But it needs at least kotlin 1.3 . Should I incorporate it in my answer and mention you?

Comment: Yes. Please add this and you can mention me.

Comment: @AbhayAgarwal thank you for your comment! I edited my answer! i would still recommend to use `in` (infix function) instead of `contains` because it increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You just need to `flatten` the values of the result `Map`.

```
val w = s.groupBy({ it }, { x -> u.filter { it.contains(x) } })
            .mapValues { it.value.flatten() }
```

My solution `map` the first collection to pairs from each element to the list where it appears, and then `groupBy` the result list.

**Example**

```
val w = s.map { elem -> Pair(elem, u.filter { list -> elem in list }) }
    .groupBy ({ it.first }, { it.second })
    .mapValues { it.value.flatten() }

check(w[1] == listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(1, 4, 7), listOf(1, 5, 9)))
check(w[9] == listOf(listOf(1, 5, 9)))

println(w)
```

**Output**

```
{1=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]], 9=[[1, 5, 9]]}
```